# Reading the Superblock

Tags: inode, superblock

I know that in Unix (specifically, Mac OS X) the superblock stores information about the layout of data on the disk, including the disk addresses at which the inodes begin and end.  I want to scan the list of inodes in my program to look for deleted files.  How can I find the disk address at which the inodes begin?  I have looked at the statfs command but it does not provide this information.

Comment: Surely this depends highly on the filesystem. I realize you want to bypass that, but it is free to implement files however they want.

Comment: Continuation of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/342057/reading-a-sector-on-the-boot-disk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mention Mac OS X, let's assume you mean to do this for HFS+ only. The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS_Plus) provides some information about possible ways to start, for instance it says this about the on-disk layout:

> Sectors 0 and 1 of the volume are HFS boot blocks. These are identical to the boot blocks in an HFS volume. They are part of the HFS wrapper.
>
> Sector 2 contains the Volume Header equivalent to the Master Directory Block in an HFS volume. The Volume Header stores a wide variety of data about the volume itself, for example the size of allocation blocks, a timestamp that indicates when the volume was created or the location of other volume structures such as the Catalog File or Extent Overflow File. The Volume Header is always located in the same place.
>
> The Allocation File which keeps track of which allocation blocks are free and which are in use. It is similar to the Volume Bitmap in HFS, each allocation block is represented by one bit. A zero means the block is free and a one means the block is in use. The main difference with the HFS Volume Bitmap, is that the Allocation File is stored as a regular file, it does not occupy a special reserved space near the beginning of the volume. The Allocation File can also change size and does not have to be stored contiguously within a volume.

It becomes more complicated, after that. Read up on [B* trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B*-tree), for instance.

I'm no Mac OS user, but it would surprise me if there weren't already tools written to scan for deleted files, perhaps some are open source and could provide a more concrete  starting point?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have quite some trouble to find deleted files because there's not much left on the disk to find when you delete a file.

If you delete a file on a FAT (or UDF) file system, its directory entry simply gets marked as "deleted", with most of the dir entry still intact.

On HFS volumes, due to their use of B-Trees, deleted edits *must* be removed from the directory or else searching for items wouldn't work any more efficiently (well, this argument may be a bit weak, but fact is that deleted entries get removed and overwritten).

So, unless the deletion took place by writing over a directory sector by accident, or by re-initializing the volume, you'll not find much.