# os x el capitan chmod error

Tags: macos, osx-elcapitan

I have upgraded from os x yosemite to el capitan,  after upgrading I am trying to run "chmod u+s /usr/sbin/pppd" command to fix a error that I am getting in sonicwall netextender client.

Running the command gives the below error

```
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /usr/sbin/pppd: Operation not permitted
```

The file is marked as restricted when I list the files in /usr/sbin folder using "ls -lO" command.

Has anyone got a similar error when running chmod for a file marked as restricted?

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/193379/78473 should provide a sufficient explanation and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30768087/restricted-folder-files-in-os-x-el-capitan?rq=1 is super-similar to your q (i.e. this cld get marked as a dup)

Comment: Thanks, disabling SIP fixed the error.