# Hide Python icon from OS X El Capitan dock?

Tags: python, macos, osx-elcapitan, dock

Before OS X El Capitan came out it was easily possible to hide the Python app from the dock when you run a python script. Since El Capitan is out, this is not the case anymore. If I try to edit the Info.plist with root permission it still says that the file is in read-only mode. I even tried to log in as root and then edit it but it doesn't help.

I run a few python scripts via crontab.

Does anyone have a solution for hiding Python? I'd appreciate it.

Comment: The problem has to do with different handling of sudo in OS X El Capitan. Some areas are by default non-sudo-able after upgrade due to a feature called "SIP" (System Intregrity Protection). The accepted answer on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30768087/restricted-folder-files-in-os-x-el-capitan) should solve the problem.

Comment: It worked out, thanks! Didn't know that they introduced this feature with El Capitan.

Comment: I didn't either. Here's the long version, if you're interested: http://www.macworld.com/article/2948140/os-x/private-i-el-capitans-system-integrity-protection-will-shift-utilities-functions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has to do with different permissions associated with `sudo` in OS X El Capitan. Some areas are by default non-`sudo`-able after upgrade due to a feature called "SIP" (System Intregrity Protection). The accepted answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30768087/restricted-folder-files-in-os-x-el-capitan) solves the issue.